# Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string or a class/function but got: undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I am trying to implement pure function for my login form and I am using redux-form.

And I got this error in my unit test:

```
Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string  or a class/function but got: undefined.
```

Here is my component that I want to test:

```
import { Username } from './presentation/LoginPage.js';
export class LoginPage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { error, handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting } = this.props;
    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div>
          <label>Username</label>
          <Field 
            name="username" 
            component={username =>
              <Username username />
          } />
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

LoginPage.propTypes = {
};

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'login',  // a unique identifier for this form
})(LoginPage);
```

And here is my pure component:

```
export const Username = (props) => {
  const { username } = props;
  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" {...username} placeholder="Username" />
      {username.touched && username.error && <span>{username.error}</span>}
    </div>);
};
```

When I play it in the browser I got `reduce is not defined`. It works fine when I remove the `<Field />`

Is there something obvious did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ah I think I am mixing the syntax for `Field` between v6 and 5. Field is available for redux-form v6.

Answer (score 2):

You have strange render with `Username` component

```
<Username username />
```

It is short syntax for the following

```
<Username username={true} />
```

According to rest of the code, here should be

```
<Username username={username} />
```

Comment: that is true. Thanks for noticing that as well